# Google Drive Api can't connect/authorize to google account

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to build an android app that integrates google drive api and uses the drive as the storage storage for it however I am after running into issue with it from the very beginning.
I've been trying to follow the official guide available at: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started
and also another guide I found https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/ and even downloading the source code and just replacing my API Key however with both of these guides I run into the exact same issue.

Whenever I try to test run the app to see if the app is connecting to the drive i get the following output in the console:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "app.googledrive/app.googledrive.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 2889 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.googledrive-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.googledrive, real application class is null.

              [ 01-16 12:33:01.211  1561: 1584 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x953a3740, tid 1584
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.googledrive-1/lib/x86
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2930: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x94efd500, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Google Drive Activity: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{e061739: android.os.BinderProxy@2c1717e}, message=null}
```

Also the Google Sign in is popping up to add an account to me it means that it connects to the google server but doesn't recognize account/sign in for one or the other reason. I've also tried regenerating the keystore and adding it again to the developers console and using an unrestricted key however the same exact issue comes up.

I would highly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to solve this issue, thanks.

Comment: Try on device, it may be some issue with emulator for sign in

Comment: Thanks @avinash for the suggestions. I did try to run it directly on an android device however it still doesn't allow me to choose an account and proceed as whenever I click on my account in the device the following message still comes up in the android studio:

Comment: `01-17 13:35:13.375 9923-9923/app.googledrive D/AppTracker: App Event: start

01-17 13:35:13.413 9923-9923/app.googledrive I/Google Drive Activity: GoogleApiClient connection failed:
 
ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{a77a4d3: android.os.BinderProxy@3009081}, message=null}

01-17 13:35:13.429 9923-9923/app.googledrive D/AppTracker: App Event: stop

01-17 13:35:13.445 9923-9923/app.googledrive D/AbstractTracker: Event success

01-17 13:35:13.463 9923-9923/app.googledrive D/AbstractTracker: Event success
`

Comment: Strange I have used the sample from https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started, but didn't got issue. Is it possible to post your code, and make sure the API is enabled on console

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but it will help you.

Start by defining which Google Account you will be saving to. The whole enchilada is totally different if the user will be using his own account, or some centralised account.

Next you need to decide which API/SDK you wish to use. Assuming you want the user to save to his own Google account, you have a choice between using the REST API (with or without the Java SDK) or the Android API. The REST API allows access to all Drive features, but only works when the handset is online and requires a bit of wrangling to get authorised. The Google Drive Android API (GDAA) offers a subest of features, but is easier to get working and has the advantage of allowing offline access.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid for the answer it seems to me I was trying to use the wrong API for the purpose of my application in this case. I am planning to use one centralized account for my application that will be used for storage and accessing of the data by the android handset on the google drive. I am also not worried about the connection as the handset will be required to be online for other features as well.
I will try to google more in this case about the REST API, I am guessing that the credentials will need to be hardcoded in the application?

Comment: If you want to use a single centralised account, then yes, the credentials need to be stored in the app. You have a choice of using a Service Account where the credential is a key pair, or a regular account where the credential is a refresh token. Be aware that most of the sample code you will encounter is for the use case where your app will be accessing a user's own account, and so needs to deal  with authentication and authorization.

Comment: I don't know if I am really that dumb or what but I've been trying to look up for the last few days the official documentation and other threads out here trying to find some examples on setting up the REST API and later proceeding with the service account to authorize but I seem to not be able to get this small but vital part working. I know this might be a little too much to ask for but you don't happen to have a sample code for these 2 things? (Setting up the drive REST API for the android device and authenticating with service account) I really appreciate your help :)!!!