# Uploading local files to Google Drive using Drive application and without APIs

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api, kotlin, android-file

I am trying to upload local files to Google drive using installed Drive application.
Code:

```
    driveIntent.`package` = "com.google.android.apps.docs"
    driveIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    val fileId = File(this.cacheDir.path + "/SensorReport.pdf")
    val url = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/" + fileId
    driveIntent.data = Uri.parse(url)
    driveIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActitivty(driveIntent)
```

Problem is that it only shows "Google account selector" dialog box and when an account is selected, the dialog is dismissed and there is no notification or Drive application screen.

Comment: You may want to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503195/infinite-choose-an-account-loop-when-using-google-drive-api). It stated that it might happen if you did not create the credentials for your app. You may also check this related thread if it works: [Google Drive Api can't connect/authorize to google account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676982/google-drive-api-cant-connect-authorize-to-google-account).